# some part of keyboard types different keys

Tags: laptop, windows-10, keyboard

I have a Dell Inspiron 7537 running windows 10.

The problem started after I forced shutdown my laptop when it stopped responding (Thanks windows 10).

After restarting some keys of my keyboard were, so to speak, mapped onto different part of the keyboard (for example pressing the key 7 would print ;)

Using [PassMark Keyboard Test](http://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm), I was able to see the following anamolies in my keyboard

- Pressing one key results in a second key getting recognized ( eg L key is mapped onto the F6 key)
- Pressing one key results in the simultaneous press of another key (pressing only CTRL causes both CTRL and ALT to be recognized)
- Function key working only intermittently

I have tried the following with no effect on the situation

- Uninstalled and reinstalled the keyboard from the device manager.
- Updated ALL the drivers from Dell's website.
- Removed and readded keyboard layout from the Regional Settings options in windows.

Furthermore the laptop keyboard exhibits the same behaviour on the linux installation I have on the laptop.

I had the EXACT same problem a couple of months ago which resolved on its own therefore I am reluctant to think that it is a hardware issue.

Any suggestions on how to sort this out and/or confirm it is a hardware problem?

Comment: Can you try out an external keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of restarts, the problem resolved on its own. Also, the problem has not occurred since the past two months.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternate/roundabout solution, which might not be what you want.

You can use a 3rd party program called Sharpkeys. Sharpkeys requires Microsoft .NET framework 4.0 or more.

You can install Sharpkeys from their website [here](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

After that, you can start remapping your keys to the original ones. Though this isn't pleasable, this is just an alternative.

[image: Key mapping with Sharpkeys]